# Infinite long sequence convolution error

Tags: convolution

I use version 11.2.
[image]

```
Convsum[f_, g_, k_] := 
 Sum[Function[k, f][i] Function[k, g][
    k - i], {i, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
F[k_] := a^k UnitStep[k]
G[k_] := b^k UnitStep[k]
Convsum[F[k], G[k], k];
Simplify[PowerExpand[%], Element[{k}, Integers]]
```

When b=2,
[image]

Why?

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag; it is reserved for things that have been vetted by the community as an actual bug (as explained in the `bugs` tag wiki). Can you please explain more in your post about why you think this is in error?

Comment: Please forgive me for asking the question for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

When using 2 instead of `b`, Mathematica can use the fact that `2>0`. So, you can get the simplification you want by adding the assumption `b>0`:

```
sum = Assuming[
    k ∈ Integers && b>0,
    Sum[a^i UnitStep[i] b^(k-i) UnitStep[k-i], {i,-Infinity,Infinity}]
];
sum //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b} & k\geq 0 \\
>  0 & \operatorname{True}
> \end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a built-in function for convolution -- you don't need to program it yourself:

```
f[k_] := a^k UnitStep[k];
g[k_] := b^k UnitStep[k];
DiscreteConvolve[f[k], g[k], k, n]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a great solution to my problem.